# Overlapping bars in c3 (v4) bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, bar-chart, c3.js

I would like to make a reference to this previous question:

[stacked bar chart with overlapping bars C3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121771/stacked-bar-chart-with-overlapping-bars-c3js)

However, my only problem is that I want to overlap columns to show (as an example) that from 4 students, 3 have passed the subject. Right now I have a bar with height 3 and on top a bar with height 4, which makes it 7 and I want a bar of 4 with a bar of 3 overlapping. How can I change my code? Thanks:

```
        <div id="chart3"></div>
        <script>
            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#chart3',
                data: {
                    url: '../static/CSV/Chart_data/number_students.csv,
                    x:'AC_YEAR',
                    type: 'bar',
                    groups: [
                        ['Total women', 'Passed women'],
                        ['Total men', 'Passed men']
                    ],
                },
                axis: {
                    y: {
                        label: {
                            text:"Number of students",
                            position: "outer-middle"
                        },
                    },
                    x: {
                        label: {
                            text:"Year",
                            position: "outer-center"
                        },
                    }
                },
                size: {
                    height: 400,
                    width: 800
                },
                bar:{
                    width:{ratio:0.7}
                },
                legend: {
                        show: true,
                        position: 'inset',
                        inset: {
                            anchor: 'top-right',
                            x: 10,
                            y: 5,
                            step: 2
                        }
                    }        
            }); 
        </script>
```

The csv file number_students is:

```
AC_YEAR,Passed women,Passed men,Total women,Total men
2010,72,239,98,315
2011,77,227,83,276
2012,65,226,93,298
2013,54,215,77,283
2014,63,233,88,294
2015,49,205,64,267
```

The current one looks like this:

[image: Without overlapping bars]

And the one I want should overlap so that, in 2010 for example, we would see only a little of green (the 7 female students that did not passed) because the blue in the front is only 7 units less than the green. And in the right 29 units of red color (the male students that did not passed).

Comment: Can you show us what your chart should look like?

Comment: Thanks @AdityaK see the edited question above

Comment: Is it okay if the solution uses d3?

Comment: Yes, @AdityaK no problem, but I am not very familiar with it, so if you could please show exactly how you would modify my previous code, that would help a lot! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never worked with `c3` before so I have no idea if there is any chart in `c3` that can particularly do this. I was able to solve this by using `d3`.

Firstly `c3` uses `path` for bars instead of `rects` for some reason otherwise changing the `width` of the bars could have been easier.

What I did was first store all the dimensions of the bars for all four categories into four different arrays using `d3.select(**bars**).node().getBBox()` and then adjust the `y` and `width` for `Total women` and `Total men` bars according to `y` attributes of `Passed women` and `Passed men` because we want to overlap them.

Then hide all the `path` elements created by `c3` and then wrap all this in a function to be called when the user resizes the browser window.

Here'a the complete [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aditya_kk29/1Lgwno23/) or a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HmqoaJaBbgijx2JEgItD?p=info)

Comment: Thanks @AdityaK it is awesome! But I dont know why with my csv it is not working... I want to create it with the csv because I will be modifying it... Could you show me how to do it with the csv as well? Sorry to annoy you! And also, the comments from the JS, do I have to put them as code? Thanks!

Comment: I think my problem is that when charging the data with the url, the keys are not assigned and, therefore, the function is not working properly. But how can I assign keys if data comes from csv?

Comment: with the csv file (that I would be modifying, so I cannot insert the data directly) shown on the question. I can upload it so that you run the code with the file and try it yourself! @AdityaK

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvijsuki53eamic/number_students.csv?dl=0 @AdityaK

Comment: @MTT Tried reading the csv from the dropbox link you shared but failed. 
I have added a plunkr (check updated answer) which is reading the csv using a the Papa parse library.

Comment: Thank you very much! @AdityaK did I required jquery in the previous version? Maybe that was my problem!

Comment: @MTT Yes I did use jQuery just for the window resize function. You can eliminate that and use pure javascript alternatively.

Comment: And sorry @AdityaK, could you do it without Papa parse? Like you did here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254789/histogram-with-values-from-csv). You are saving me! Thanks!!

Comment: @MTT I did try it earlier by using only d3 but was doing something wrong. I figured it out. Please check the updated Plunker.

Comment: @MTT Glad I could help. Cheers!